# How can I change the border color and size of a TabControl?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, tabcontrol

How can I change the border size/style/color of my `TabControl` to make it blend in with my form's background color?

I am unable to find any property for this in Visual Studio. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: No, there is no such property. I'm not sure what the resulting control would look like; I don't think I've ever seen one. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Cody The border of the tab looks weird, the left side = right side = bottom = 2 while top = 1  I want it to be even in all sides.

Comment: I don't really know what you're describing. I'm looking at a `TabControl` right now, and I don't see that the borders are uneven. Would changing the `Padding` property of your **`TabPage`** be helpful?

Comment: @Cody I have posted a screenshot

Comment: Yeah, you completely forgot to mention that you'd assigned your form a custom background color and you were still seeing the *standard* control color of the `TabControl` around the edges.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized its not a border. So is there any way around this ?

Comment: I am not sure how to describe this question correctly, if someone understood me then please edit my question suitably.

Comment: Probably use `OwnerDrawFixed`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063061/how-can-i-make-a-transparent-tabpage/30064743#30064743

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `TabControl` isn't expecting to be placed over a custom-colored background. What you're seeing at the edges is the standard color used for 3D controls. You normally wouldn't notice that if you hadn't changed the background color of your form. By default, they're the same color.

I don't know of any good way to fix this. The `TabControl` doesn't expose an awful lot of built-in options for customizing its appearance. You're going to have to owner draw and paint it a custom color yourself.

Visit [this page](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm) for some different options and sample code. I suspect that the [Completely OwnerDraw TabControl](http://dotnetrix.co.uk/tabcontrol.htm#tip2) is what you need; use the code that's provided and customize it to your liking. Be thankful someone else has already done all the work for you, because implementing this yourself is non-trivial.

Also note that changing the `DrawMode` to "OwnerDrawFixed" will disable themes. Your control will look like it came straight out of Windows 95, instead of getting drawn in the Luna or Aero theme styles. Not a big deal if you're completely customizing how it's painted, but a pain in the rear if all you want is to change the background color.

Comment: @abcd: Sure; sorry this isn't as easy as you were hoping. In general, the WinForms controls weren't designed for custom colors; by default, they respect the user's current Windows theme. I personally like it that way. If I happen to *hate* the color blue and have changed all instances of blue in the default theme to green or red, and your application comes along and splashes blue all over, I'm probably going to be less than thrilled. Not trying to alter the colors of the built-in controls not only makes less work for you, but also preserves a more predictable experience for your users.

Comment: Don't worry, the app is totally customizable , he or she can change color theme , background image , change border size , change font size ... everything I can possibly think of :)

Comment: Works on .NET Core 5 Winforms. Thank you so much for pointing this out! I should make a github repository with the respective credits for this because it's gold.

Answer (score 3):

if you are trying to hide the borders and blend them with the form's backcolor,
put the TabControl in a container like "Panel" control and make the size of the TabConrol bigger than the Panel control size, but this will cover the Tabs Buttons also, and for this issue you can add button for each tab and set the button's click event to to change the TabControl's SelectedTab property.
Note: you can keep the TabControl in a location where you can change the tab in designtime then add the small following code on form's Load event to hide the Tabs buttons on runtime:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

TabControl.ItemSize = New Size(0, 1)
TabControl.SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed

End Sub
```

Comment: After like 20 attempts with custom classes this solution took me 5 minutes... only thing is u do need a resize event for the panel that resizes the TabControl  to keep it from becoming weird.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do it would be to drop the tab control onto a panel that's slightly smaller. The borders on the tab control won't show, and then you can customize the borders on the panel however you want.

Answer (score -3):

```
Me.TabPage1.BackColor = Color.Blue
```

Try this, it will be helpful to you.

Comment: No, that changes the color of the `TabPage`, not the container control. You'll still see the border around the edges. He already has a custom color for his `TabPage` in the screenshot.