# How can I make a transparent tabPage?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, transparent, tabpage

How can I make a transparent tabPage? I found solutions like set both Form's `BackColor` and `TransparencyKey` to a color like `Color.LimeGreen` or override `OnPaintBackground` with a empty method but TabPage doesn't have neither TransparencyKey`property nor`OnPaintBackground` method. How can I do that?

Comment: `TabPage1.BackColor = Color.Transparent` chage the TabPage1 to the name of your control and try that..

Comment: In short, you can't. WinForms is a wrapper around native Win32 Controls and GDI, neither of which support true Z-ordering of UI components with alpha-channels. For these kinds of effects you'll need to use WPF or another UI framework.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TabControl is a native Windows component, it always draws the tab pages opaque with no built-in support for transparency.  Solving this requires a little helping of out-of-the-box thinking, a tab control with transparent tab pages simply devolves to just the tabstrip being visible.  All you have to do is use panels to host the controls that are now on the tab pages and make the correct one visible with the SelectedIndexChanged event.

Best to stick this in a derived class so you can still use the tab control normally at design time.  Add a new class to your project and paste the code shown below.  Compile.  Drop the new control from the top of the toolbox onto the form, replacing the existing one.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class TransparentTabControl : TabControl {
    private List<Panel> pages = new List<Panel>();

    public void MakeTransparent() {
        if (TabCount == 0) throw new InvalidOperationException();
        var height = GetTabRect(0).Bottom;
        // Move controls to panels
        for (int tab = 0; tab < TabCount; ++tab) {
            var page = new Panel {
                Left = this.Left, Top = this.Top + height,
                Width = this.Width, Height = this.Height - height,
                BackColor = Color.Transparent,
                Visible = tab == this.SelectedIndex
            };
            for (int ix = TabPages[tab].Controls.Count - 1; ix >= 0; --ix) {
                TabPages[tab].Controls[ix].Parent = page;
            }
            pages.Add(page);
            this.Parent.Controls.Add(page);
        }
        this.Height = height /* + 1 */;
    }

    protected override void OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) {
        base.OnSelectedIndexChanged(e);
        for (int tab = 0; tab < pages.Count; ++tab) {
            pages[tab].Visible = tab == SelectedIndex;
        }
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing) {
        if (disposing) foreach (var page in pages) page.Dispose();
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Call the MakeTransparent() method in the form's Load event handler:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    transparentTabControl1.MakeTransparent();
}
```

Comment: This works amazingly well. I created a custom control from this class and dragged the control to my Form. But there's a issue at design-time: once I run the application, the control became totally invisible. Right after I put the control on my form it looks like this http://prntscr.com/720szz after I compile the application and back to VS GUI designer it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/720t4a It seems it's gone but it's still there so far I can tell by loooking at the list of controls on form on the ComboBox right above  the Property Grid.

Comment: Actually, the `TransparentTabControl` control itself isn't in there  anymore (after the compilation) only its TabPages: http://prntscr.com/720z9s

Comment: Noted, OnParentChanged() was a late change and the designer doesn't like it very much.  I punted the problem, works much better now.

Comment: This is awesome! I get how it works, and isn't even that complex as I throught it would be to make it transparent. Your code is alwas that pieces of elegant lines!

Comment: Nice piece of code but It doesn't work when you're painting  gradient background on a form.

Comment: Panel has good support for transparency effects.  Set the panels' BackColor to Color.Transparent.