# Changing the background on a tabPageBackground

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

The code itself works but my `TabPages`'s `BackgroundImage` still remains the same even if I change it into transparent. So how can I make an Image appear for the background of an `TabPage`. All it does now is show the image behind the `TabPage`'s Background.

```
Random randomPic = new Random();

private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     int ShowPic = 0;

     ShowPic = randomPic.Next(1, 3);

     if(ShowPic == 1)
     {
          BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"myndir/Animal-1.jpg");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`BackgroundImage` changes the Form's `BackgroundImage`. To change the `TabPages`'s `BackgroundImage` you should try this:

```
tabControl1.TabPages[0].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"myndir/Animal-1.jpg");
```

And if you want to change all `TabPages`'s `BackgroundImage` try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabControl1.TabCount; i++)
{
     tabControl1.TabPages[i].BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"myndir/Animal-1.jpg");                
}
```

Also if you want to make a transparent `TabPage`, have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063061/how-can-i-make-a-transparent-tabpage) post.