# C# Change the Default TabPage in TabControl using Custom TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol, tabpage

I created a Custom `TabControl` and a custom `TabPage` like below:

Custom `TabControl` code:

```
public class MyCustomTabControl : TabControl
{
   //Some Custom Properties

   public MyCustomTabControl () : base()
    {
        base.Width = 200;
        base.Height = 100;

    }
}
```

Custom`TabPage`:

```
public class MyCustomTabPage : TabPage
{
    //Some Custom Properties

    public MyCustomTabPage() : base()
    {                     
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
    }
}
```

How can I do it so that when I add my custom control `MyCustomTabControl` in the form, it add the custom `TabPage` named `MyCustomTabPage`. Currently it adding the `TabPage` from windows.

Comment: You can't do it with the designer, you'll have to use code.  Write it in the constructor of the form, after the InitializeComponent() call.  Beware that TabControl [does not support transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30064743/17034).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You Need to do some steps, first define a class e.g `MyCustomTabCollection` and implement all Three Interfaces methods for your `MyCustomTabCollection` class, then  Declare an instance of `MyCustomTabCollection` on your `MyCustomTabControl` as a `public` property.

> **Implement interfaces**

```
public class MyCustomTabPageCollection : IList, ICollection, IEnumerable
{
    // implement all three interfaces
}
```

> **Implement all methods**

```
public object this[int index] { get => throw new NotImplementedException(); set => throw new NotImplementedException(); }

public bool IsReadOnly => throw new NotImplementedException();

public bool IsFixedSize => throw new NotImplementedException();

public int Count => throw new NotImplementedException();

public object SyncRoot => throw new NotImplementedException();

public bool IsSynchronized => throw new NotImplementedException();

public int Add(object value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Clear()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public bool Contains(object value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void CopyTo(Array array, int index)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public int IndexOf(object value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Insert(int index, object value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void Remove(object value)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

public void RemoveAt(int index)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

> **Declare your CustomTabPageCollection**

```
public class MyCustomTab : TabControl
{
    public MyCustomTabPageCollection TabPages { get; set; }

    public MyCustomTab() : base()
    {
        base.Width = 200;
        base.Height = 100;

    }
}
```

If there is a problem yet, let me know.